# Error ao tentar adicionar classe dinamicamente com classList.add() e className

Tags: javascript

Se eu criar um elemento e já adicionar uma classe nele assim:

```
let paragrafo = document.createElement('p').classList.add('text')
```

Depois tentar adicionar um elemento filho nele assim:

```
text = document.createTextNode('texto')<br>
paragrafo.appendChild(text)
```

Fica dando erro de: `Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined`.

Já se eu mudar e tentar adicionar com className da error de : `paragrafo.appendChild is not a function`

Porém se eu tirar o classList/className lá de cima, e não adicionar uma classe funciona normal, porém eu preciso adicionar essa classe. Por qual motivo eu tenho esse resultado e como posso criar o elemento e logo em seguida adicionar a classe usando apenas JavaScript puro?

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você cria o elemento:

```
let paragrafo = document.createElement('p');
```

Depois você adiciona a classe:

```
paragrafo.classList.add('text');
```

Você não pode fazer as duas coisas ao mesmo tempo.

---

Outra forma seria:

```
let paragrafo = document.createElement('p');
paragrafo.className = 'text';
```

O `.classList.add` adiciona uma classe, mesmo se já houverem outras (ou nenhuma). Já o `.className` define uma classe única ao elemento (reescreve o atributo `class`).

Answer (score 2):

O que esta acontecendo é que você esta codificando javascript puro como se estive-se usando jQuery.

Quando você coloca:

```js
console.log( 'createElement' , document.createElement('p') );
    /// retorna um HTMLElement  <p>

console.log( 'classList' , document.createElement('p').classList );
    /// retorna um DOMTokenList  []

console.log( 'classList.add' , document.createElement('p').classList.add("minhaclasse") );
    /// retorna undefined
```

Ou seja, seu `let paragrafo` esta recebendo **undefined** e não um **HTMLElement**.